# Creating an Emailing kit

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, email, mailkit

I'm trying to crate an email kit (something like MailChimp but with some extensions on it. Is it ideal to use the smtp server directly for sending newsletter and the likes so that every newsletter sent would be stored at the smtp server or I should rather use POP3 server and then store all the sent emails for analytics, because to me, I'm seeing this as being easier as I can easily access my database and add custom data fields like tags to classify my emails?